# How to set row wise data in test innotation using dataprovider?

Tags: automated-tests, dataprovider, data-driven-tests

[For UI part please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBn4y.png) [For excel sheet click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTdro.png)Unable to provide row-wise data in test cases.
 I have tried below code. Data provider used for fetching the data from excel. Unlimited Data can be under excel sheet.

```
    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] ReadVariant() throws IOException
    {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream= new 
  FileInputStream(file_location);
```

//Excel sheet file location get mentioned here

```
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fileInputStream); //get my workbook 
        worksheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);// get my sheet from workbook
        XSSFRow Row=worksheet.getRow(0);//get my Row which start from 0   
        SheetName= worksheet.getSheetName();

        int RowNum = worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        c1 = RowNum-1;

        str2 = Integer.toString(c1);

        System.out.println("Total Row available:" +RowNum);
```

// count my number of Rows

```
        int ColNum= Row.getLastCellNum(); // get last ColNum 

         Object Data[][]= new Object[RowNum-1][ColNum]; // pass my  count data 
      in array

            for(int i=0; i<RowNum-1; i++)
```

//Loop work for Rows

```
            {  
                XSSFRow row= worksheet.getRow(i+1);

                for (int j=0; j<ColNum; j++) //Loop work for colNum
                {
                    if(row==null)
                        Data[i][j]= "";
                    else
                    {
                        XSSFCell cell= row.getCell(j);
                        if(cell==null)
                            Data[i][j]= ""; //if it get Null value it pass no data 
                        else
                        {
                            String value=formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                            Data[i][j]=value; 
          This formatter get my all values as string i.e integer, float all type data value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return Data;
    }
```

Mentioned about the test that needs to perform.

```
     @Test //Test method
      (dataProvider="ReadVariant") //It get values from ReadVariant function 
      method

    //Here my all parameters from the excel sheet are mentioned.
     public void AddVariants(String Qty, String ProductName, String Price) 
    throws Exception
       {
```

//For the first row

```
       driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_form_inventory_item_id")).click();
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_autogen3_search")).sendKeys(ProductName           
     +Keys.ENTER);
     Product name entered
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.findElement(By.id("form_quantity")).sendKeys(Qty);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.findElement(By.id("form_price")).sendKeys(Price);
```

//All values entered in first row

```
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

//For second row

```
      driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_form_inventory_item_id1")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_autogen4_search")).sendKeys(ProductName 
        +Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("form_quantity1")).sendKeys(Qty);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("form_price1")).sendKeys(Price);
```

able to enter the first UI row but
unable to enter the second-row data in second UI rows.

So please suggest how to deal with this.